# Is there a way in iCalendar to specify an event in the second hour of a DST overlap?

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

From https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.5

```
  If, based on the definition of the referenced time zone, the local
  time described occurs more than once (when changing from daylight
  to standard time), the DATE-TIME value refers to the first
  occurrence of the referenced time.  Thus, TZID=America/
  New_York:20071104T013000 indicates November 4, 2007 at 1:30 A.M.
  EDT (UTC-04:00).
```

Since date-time values in RFC 5545 don't accept offsets, how do I specify a timestamp in that second hour, rather than the first?

Comment: Specify it in the UTC timezone

Comment: @anmari But if you do that, wouldn't that mean that DST changes are not handled properly for recurrence instances?

Comment: What do you mean by not handled properly?  Do you have an example?  UTC is there to ensure that time can be unambiguously defined.   Receiving systems should then convert appropriately for the timezone that the user is in and their daylight savings status.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time